# Storing Click Event in chrome.strorage (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting and have failed to tap into chrome.storage but it still resets my javascript each time I click the extension icon or refresh the current page. I'm attempting to save a click event, while also removing an element from the DOM of the current tab. Would like to be able to save this so you won't have to fire off the extension after every window reload.

**Here's my manifest file:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DOM ITEM REMOVER",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description" : "Quickly Remove Item from DOM",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"

    },
  "background": { "scripts": ["jquery.js","popup.js" , "content_scripts.js"] }
}
```

**my popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
    body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.container {
  width: 230px;
  background: white;
  padding: 2em 0em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inner {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.dets {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.the-button {
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #A1AE92;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#on {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#show {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ball , .ball-2 {
  height: 35px;
  width: 45px;
  background: #152432;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.ball.is-active {
  transform: translateX(-55px) scale(1.1);
}


    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="dets">Tool Remover</div>
        <button id="clickTrigger" class="the-button">
            <span id="on">Hide</span>
            <span id="show">Show</span>
            <span class="ball"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**my popup.js**

```
var showing = true;

function runContentScript() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'jquery.js'
  }, function() {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
          file: 'content_scripts.js'
      });
  });
}


var changetxt = function(){

    if(showing){
        $('.ball').addClass('is-active')
        showing = false;
        console.log(showing);
    }
    else if(!showing){
        $('.ball').removeClass('is-active')
        showing = true;
        console.log(showing);
    }


  chrome.storage.local.set({'value': showing}, function() {
    runContentScript();
  });

}

$('#clickTrigger').on('click', changetxt)
```

**my content_scripts.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('.selector').hide(100)
});
```

Comment: You're not reading current value from chrome.storage.local at the start of the popup script.

Comment: In the `background`, you should not be loading any of the scripts you are currently listing. The background script/page is a separate scope/context. There is rarely a reason to load jQuery there. Your *popup.js* is intended for your popup, not as a background script. Your *content_script.js* is clearly intended as a content script, not a background script. In general, it's a bad idea to load scripts into multiple scopes/contexts. Generally, this should only be done with libraries.